# Bash surprisingly evaluates "${x:-''}" to (literally) '' instead of the empty string

Tags: bash

The following program

```
#!/bin/bash

x=
y="${x:-''}"
z=${x:-''}
k="${x:-}"
l=${x:-}

echo "x = [$x]"
echo "y = [$y]"
echo "z = [$z]"
echo "k = [$k]"
echo "l = [$l]"
```

([shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says 'no issues detected')

yields

```
x = []
y = ['']
z = []
k = []
l = []
```

The Parameter Expansion denoted by `${parameter:-word}` is described as follows in the man page of *bash*:

> ${parameter:-word}: Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or
>   null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of 
>   parameter is substituted.

How is it justified that evaluating `"${x:-''}"` results in the string `''` instead of the empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the expansion in `y="${x:-''}"` is double-quoted, the characters in the substitution word are also considered to be double-quoted. The result is similar to `y=${x:"''"}` except that in the latter case, the contents of `$x` are not quoted (also see the note below).

The same would apply to using glob characters (eg. `*`) in the substitution.

Note: As pointed out by @thatotherguy in a comment, the substitution word must have balanced quotes (and braces), even if the outermost expansion is quoted. So `y="${x:-'}"` is not valid even though `y=${x:-"'"}` would be. That's because the closing `}` for the parameter substitution is:

> the first `}` not escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an embedded  arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter expansion.

(quoted from `man bash` but very similar wording can be found in Posix)

Additionally, double quotes are not quoted inside double-quotes. So in `y="${x:-""}"`, *all* of the double quotes are removed by quote removal.

Comment: As a counter-example, `y="${x:-'}"` is unterminated even though `" ' "` by itself is fine.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Yes, that's a good point. That is the result of a different clause. I'll add a note.

Comment: Interestingly `"${x:-\'}"` yields an escaped single quote in `bash`. Also `"${x:-'}"` produces a single quote in both `ksh93` and `pdksh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I make no claims about the Posix-conformance of the alternate shells, but if that is true then they are not. As for the your first example, that's because `\x` in double quotes is only special if `x` is `$`, `\``, `"`, `\ ` or a newline. For any other character, including a single-quote, the backslash is retained. (That's in both man bash and Posix,)

Comment: Thanks rici. You write _double quotes are not quoted inside double-quotes. So in `y="${x:-""}"`_ ... is the right-hand side not interpreted as `"${x:-"` and `"}"` stuck together. The parser would really just read up to the first unquoted `"` to terminate the quoted string. But then it would have `${x:-` on its hand and fail. So it reads up to the first unquoted `"` after (unquoted) brace closure. This syntax is far too hairy.

Comment: @david: shell parsing is insane, no question. There are even stranger corner cases than this (backtick parsing, for example; fortunately backticks have been deprecated). I wouldn't have *predicted* this oddity either; the best I can do is try to explain it *post facto*. :-)

Comment: More fun with these bash quirks: `"${x-'}"'}"` yields `'}'`

Comment: `"${x-\e}"` and `"${x-"\\e"}"` both yield `\e`, while `"${x-"\e"}"` gives `e`.  That makes sense as concatenating quoted and unquoted characters, but that leaves me questioning why `"${x-"'"}"` is valid at all, when it's seemingly missing a terminating single-quote.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the
>   literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the
>   exception of the characters backquote, `<dollar-sign>`, and `<backslash>`

And [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06)

> Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

And most importantly, [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07)

> The quote characters ( `<backslash>`, single-quote, and double-quote) that were present in the original word shall be removed **unless they have themselves been quoted.**

Your quoting of `''` with double quotes made it literal.